# Custom style from v-for

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm getting an array through v-for and I need to use the values inside "style", so basically the value from v-for is going to be added to `style:"left"+EachValue+"px"` however I'm struggling with the syntax, and I'm not sure if something like that can be done at all. Here is the code so far:

```
<div
v-for="(item, ind) in this.stepsprogress"
:key="ind"
class="step-block"
style="left: [[EachItemHere]]px"
>
```

Through this code I can get all the items however they all come on top of each other. How can I apply each item to the style attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you need is:

`` :style="`left: ${EachValue}px`" ``

Comment: or `:style="{ left: EachValue + 'px' }"`, see [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1)